# Django 'if settings.DEBUG:' What that mean

Tags: python, django, if-statement

I am django beginner. When I code file upload, I don't understand this code

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns+=static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Why did we have to code `if settings.DEBUG:`?

Comment: `If Variable:` always means that the Variable needs to be `True` (Boolean) to execute the following code. Its the same as 'If DEBUG == True:' You have the same logic in many programming languages. For Example in JS it would be `if (var){...`
The `DEBUG` Variable is defined in your Settings.py file (at the top somewhere)

Answer (score 2):

Those two lines [allow the development server to serve user-uploaded files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development) in the `MEDIA_ROOT` directory.

You should not do this in production, so the `if settings.DEBUG` check is added. In production, you should configure your server (e.g. Nginx or Apache) to serve the media and static files, or serve them from a CDN.

Answer (score 0):

It explicitly means that if it is on development mode and not in production mode!

Comment: yeah that is known..... why be that now?
@alasdair has explained it well

Answer (score 0):

if settings.DEBUG:

To check explicitly whether we are in debug mode or not.